# Return pandas dataframe with additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I want to create a new list of dataframes that is identical to the previous one but with an added column using a functional approach.

Here's my thinking and what I've tried:

```
# I know this is possible. It will add a new column of True.
df['new_column'] = True

# However, it edits the dataframe, I want a functional approach that returns a new modified dataframe.
# Something like this.
df + ('new_column', True)

# Then I can use it in list comprehension. consider dfs is a list of dataframes.
[df + ('new_column', True) for df in dfs]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`assign()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method:

```
[df.assign(new_column = True) for df in dfs]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.assign()` method to create new data frames with extra column in a functional way:

```
[df.assign(new_column = lambda _: True) for df in dfs]
```